# JS - Join unique columns in an array with duplicates

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that have duplicate unique id's due to a join with another data set. This is due to the limitation of the API returning the data. What I want to do is to find duplicate rows and join the unique column of data in JavaScript. As an example, this is what I have:

```
var data = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Joe', type:'Red'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Smith', type:'Red'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Smith', type:'Green'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Ana', type:'Blue'},
];
```

this is the result I need:

```
var data = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Joe', type:'Red'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Smith', type:'Red, Green'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Ana', type:'Blue'},
];
```

I figured I could create a nested for loop but I believe performance wise it wouldn't be ideal. I tried using the Array.prototype.filter but couldn't achieve what I needed here.

Comment: Why not an array of types?

Comment: I need to bind the objects to a table (JQuery table) so they are all string or int. But if you have an implementation that would result it to be an array I could possibly call the join function before binding to put it back into one comma separated string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use an array of types, it's cleaner and reusable.

This approach uses the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to group the objects by `id` and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
var data = [  {id: 1, name: 'Joe', type:'Red'},  {id: 2, name: 'Smith', type:'Red'},  {id: 2, name: 'Smith', type:'Green'},  {id: 3, name: 'Ana', type:'Blue'}],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, c) => {
      (a[c.id] || (a[c.id] = Object.assign({}, c, {type: []}))).type.push(c.type);

      return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice idea using the short-circuit to populate the object if the key didn't exist and immediately hopping into array methods!

Comment: My array has a GUID as the id field, not an incremental int. Would this still work? I gave it a try and the array was returning as undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer worked and now I know about the Array.prototype.reduce method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `reduce` wrapped with `Object.values`:

```js
var data = [ {id: 1, name: 'Joe', type:'Red'}, {id: 2, name: 'Smith', type:'Red'}, {id: 2, name: 'Smith', type:'Green'}, {id: 3, name: 'Ana', type:'Blue'}, ];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,c) => 
  (r[c.id] ? r[c.id].type = `${r[c.id].type}, ${c.type}` : r[c.id] = c, r), {}))

console.log(result)
```

The idea is to check in the reduce if the key exists and if so simply concat the `types` string if not set the key.